# Waiting for a page to load in Selenium WebDriver before clicking based on url

Tags: c#, url, selenium, wait

I've got to write a small test and I'm stuck because first I have to search something on a page, then sort it (dropdown list) and then click on an item from a dynamic list.

However, before clicking on an item on the dropdwon list, the `click` is registered. The issue at hand is that the only difference I could find between sorted and unsorted page is the page address and that the chosen type of sort has `class="selected"` added and nothing more.

Implicit wait doesn't work because the items on the list still have the same class and nothing changes except the order and it treats them as loaded correctly. I have nothing I can think of I could use with explicit wait. The only solution I can think of is to wait for a specific url to load but I can't find a solution to do this.

Comment: Perhaps give more concrete examples. Show us the HTML of the dropdowns. Show us what you've tried and how they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already tried implicit waits there is a nice "hack" you can use. Instead of waiting on the C# side - inject a JavaScript variable and poll for it.

```
// once 
var script = "window.__mySecretGlobal = 'false'; " + 
             "window.addEventListener('load', function(){ " +
                  "window.__mySecretGlobal = 'true'; " + 
             "});";

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

Now, JavaScript will set a variable, you can poll for it:

```
async Task WaitForLoad(){
    var loaded = false;
    var script = "return window.__mySecretGlobal"
    while(!loaded){
        var res = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
        if(res.Equals("true")) return; // it's loaded!
        await Task.Delay(100); // try again in 100 ms
    }
}
```

For a more complete solution, you might want to pass a timeout and a cancellation token as optional parameters to that code.

This is not the prettiest code, but it works for us silently in production for years now where implicit and explicit waits failed.

Comment: Should I just paste it where it should wait or should I do something else with your code as well? It have me a ton of errors and I'm not too sure how to fix them.http://i.imgur.com/yvkbuLg.jpg

Comment: @owiec that second part is a _method_.